# Unix: Want to match the number and return should be exact match or just lesser number

Tags: unix

My input will be as: **04.02.03.00**
and my other list will be **04.02.01.00, 04.02.02.00 & 04.02.05.00**.

After comparing the input(04.02.03.00) with the given list if the exact match(04.02.03.00) is not in the list then 04.02.02.00 should return as output.

Comment: List is not fixed it can be changed & we need to check it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as an example with **bash**

```
 read INPUT

 for STRING in 04.02.01.00 04.02.02.00 04.02.05.00
 do
     if [[ "$INPUT" = $STRING ]]
     then
         FOUND=1
     fi
 done

 if [[ FOUND -ne 1 ]]
 then
     echo 04.02.02.00
 fi
```

Comment: The list is not limited. Point is to iterate from right most pair if the match is not found, by decreasing value by 1.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Michael just in order that to work i think it would need the "test", so like this. the brackets would help you though  protect urself from null variables but thats  matter of opinion.

```
 read INPUT

 for STRING in 04.02.01.00 04.02.02.00 04.02.05.00
 do
     if test "$INPUT" = $STRING
     then
         FOUND=1
     fi
 done

 if test $FOUND -ne 1 
 then
     echo 04.02.02.00
 fi
```